# Дозапись в существующий аудиофайл

Tags: java, android, аудио

У меня есть аудиофайл, который хранится на SD card, я хочу дозаписать аудио в конец этого файла, способы которые я нашла как это можно сделать - это использование `SequenceInputStream` или ffmpeg. Есть ли еще какие-то варианты как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это не закодированный, "сырой" аудиофайл `wav`, `pcm`, то дописать можно с помощью `AudioRecord` из android sdk.

Если закодированный, то чтобы дописать надо все раскодировать, дописать и снова закодировать. Если это делать на андройде, то можно воспользоваться `MediaCodec api`, зависит от кодека, надо смотреть какие поддерживает. Правда в сети мало примеров, и я в свое время не разобрался.

Другой вариант, более простой - `ffmpeg`. Здесь можно бинариник ффмпега засунуть в приложение и работать как из командной строки. Либо воспользоваться библиотекой [javaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv). Хороший пример использования [RecordActivity.java](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java).

Кодирование/декодирование через ффмпег на андройде медленно работает, поэтому в свое время на проекте всякие такие медиа дела я делал через него же, но на сервере.